# quartz with configured schedulers

Tags: quartz-scheduler

How can I create a quartz.properties file so it has declared number of scheduler with given properties to them and access them using `StdSchedulerFactory getScheduler("schedulername")` method?

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler1
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 3
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore

org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = MyScheduler2
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 1
org.quartz.jobStore.class = org.quartz.simpl.RAMJobStore
```

Comment: Every scheduler factory needing a conf file and return always same scheduler ,So I have to create new factories with new config and get scheduler of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, each scheduler needs it's own configuration properties.

Comment: each scheduler factory needs its configuration file and one scheduler factory return always same scheduler .Am i correct.

Comment: Yes.  And two (or more) scheduler factories that have been given the same properties (or at least properties that define a scheduler of the same name) will always return the same scheduler as well.